# Debugger not functioning in pycharm

Tags: python, debugging, pycharm

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W0RtC.jpg)I'm trying to debug this py file that I have but the console throws this

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/PyCharm CE.app/Contents/plugins/python-ce/helpers/pydev/_pydevd_bundle/pydevd_process_net_command.py", line 891, in process_net_command
    py_db.writer.add_command(cmd)
  File "/Applications/PyCharm CE.app/Contents/plugins/python-ce/helpers/pydev/_pydevd_bundle/pydevd_comm.py", line 355, in add_command
    self.cmdQueue.put(cmd)
AttributeError: 'Queue' object has no attribute 'put'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/PyCharm CE.app/Contents/plugins/python-ce/helpers/pydev/_pydevd_bundle/pydevd_process_net_command.py", line 891, in process_net_command
    py_db.writer.add_command(cmd)
  File "/Applications/PyCharm CE.app/Contents/plugins/python-ce/helpers/pydev/_pydevd_bundle/pydevd_comm.py", line 355, in add_command
    self.cmdQueue.put(cmd)
AttributeError: 'Queue' object has no attribute 'put'
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/PyCharm CE.app/Contents/plugins/python-ce/helpers/pydev/_pydevd_bundle/pydevd_comm.py", line 318, in _on_run
    self.process_command(cmd_id, int(args[1]), args[2])
  File "/Applications/PyCharm CE.app/Contents/plugins/python-ce/helpers/pydev/_pydevd_bundle/pydevd_comm.py", line 333, in process_command
    self.process_net_command(self.global_debugger_holder.global_dbg, cmd_id, seq, text)
  File "/Applications/PyCharm CE.app/Contents/plugins/python-ce/helpers/pydev/_pydevd_bundle/pydevd_process_net_command.py", line 909, in process_net_command
    py_db.writer.add_command(cmd)
  File "/Applications/PyCharm CE.app/Contents/plugins/python-ce/helpers/pydev/_pydevd_bundle/pydevd_comm.py", line 355, in add_command
    self.cmdQueue.put(cmd)
AttributeError: 'Queue' object has no attribute 'put'
Can't process net command: 501  1   0.1 UNIX
```

Can someone please explain me what does it mean?

it also says that " connection to python debugger failed argument for @NotNull parameter 's'"

Answer (score 0):

`AttributeError: 'Queue' object has no attribute 'put'`

This is the error message. But I'm not sure what caused it since this could be brouhgt by all kinds of issues.

Maybe check if you have a same filename in your project with the built-in file of `queue.py`? If so, you should be able to fix it by change your filename to something like `myQueue.py`

And you can provide more details of your code for locating errors.